# angular 4 jasmine mock constants

Tags: angular, jasmine

Is it possible to mock constants in angualr 4 jasmine. I have a function which i am testing and has a constant being used in it. I want to mock it and provide the value for it for each test scenario.

```
    export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: navigation.Actions): State {
        switch (action.type) {

            case navigation.GET_LINKS_COMPLETE: {

               // NavigationLinkConstants is what I want to mock 

                const filteredLinks: Navigation[] = _.filter(NavigationLinkConstants, (link) => {
                    // body of function goes here

                });

                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    links: filteredLinks
                });
            }

            default: {
                return state;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did this function come from? Where did this constant come from? If it is supposed to be mocked, it should be made a provider.

Comment: This is a reducer from ngrx..Is it a good idea to provide types in the reducer functions?

Comment: Types are always helpful but I'm not sure if it's possible to use DI in ngrx reducer. So the issue specific to ngrx and cannot be refactored to be more testable. I'd suggest to make a question more specific. It isn't clear where NavigationLinkConstants came from.

Comment: NavigationLinkConstants is just a simple const with key value pair. i.e. const test = [ {  }, { }]

Comment: You cannot mock it like that. I'm not sure what are the options with ngrx, (possibly effects). But NavigationLinkConstants should be a property on some exported object in order to mock it.